# when using `cbind()`, 'identical' inputs trigger different behaviors: row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

The following operation works fine :

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a= 1, b = 2) 
cbind(df1, c=3:4)
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 2 3
#> 2 1 2 4
```

However if I subset `df1`, even keeping it identical, I get a warning :

```
df2 <- df1[1,]
identical(df1, df2)
#> [1] TRUE
cbind(df2, c=3:4)
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 2 3
#> 2 1 2 4
```

> Warning in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE): row names were found from a
>   short variable and have been discarded

I haven't set any row names, and these are supposed to be identical, what is happening ?

Comment: If you check the row.names, it is different `row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)` and in second it is `row.names = 1L`

Answer (score 2):

`identical()` doesn't always tell the full story by default :

```r
identical(df1, df2, attrib.as.set = FALSE)
#> [1] FALSE
```

This option compares the attributes more rigorously, though here if we look at them, we can only see a difference in order, which is not the reason of the observed behavior as we'll see.

```
attributes(df1)
#> $names
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> $row.names
#> [1] 1
attributes(df2)
#> $names
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> $row.names
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

We can try to use `row.names()` but it won't help, more info however can be displayed using `.row_names_info()` and `dput()` :

```
row.names(df1) # sneaky snake!
#> [1] "1"
row.names(df2)
#> [1] "1"
.row_names_info(df1)
#> [1] -1
.row_names_info(df2)
#> [1] 1

dput(df1)
#> structure(list(a = 1, b = 2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
#> -1L))
dput(df2)
#> structure(list(a = 1, b = 2), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

In fact, `cbind.data.frame()` calls `data.frame()` which itself calls `.row_names_info()` and tests its sign before triggering the warning, and `.row_names_info(df1)` is negative while `.row_names_info(df2)` is positive.

Setting row names to `NULL` "reinitializes" the row.names.

```
row.names(df2) <- NULL
cbind(df2, c=3:4)
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 2 3
#> 2 1 2 4
```

So what the warning in essence was saying is that we were trying to recycle the rows of a `data.frame` that had row names, so row names had to be ignored for the recycling to happen. If row names are really inexistent, the recycling happens silently.

Now we can argue on the definition and relevance of what is "having no row names" here.

I'm aware that this answer doesn't answer everything (not all the how, and not any of the why), but that's all I have!